# How to restart gulp watch when git branch changes

Tags: git, gulp, gulp-watch

It's useful to have [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) building files using a `watch` task. In my case I have a task which watches a `php` directory for changes and lints/copies on change, a JS directory which concatenates and copies, and SASS which compiles to CSS on change.

If I checkout another git branch with the watch task running it quite expectedly goes insane, as literally hundreds of files change. One problem which could be solvable is that the `watch` triggers generic tasks - the PHP one for example simply re-lints and copies all PHP files, not just the one that changed. So if 50 files change, the whole stack is re-linted 50 times. Ditto for JS (because of dependencies) and SASS (because it runs compass, which then also sees every file as changed).

So at present my solution is to kill my `watch` task (which is running using [Sublime Gulp](https://github.com/NicoSantangelo/sublime-gulp)), then checkout a new branch, then re-run it. I'd imagine that any solution would either need to modify the `Sublime Gulp` plugin, or stop me using it - which would be fine if there was a quick shortcut to have the `watch` task run in the background of my terminal, and allow me to see output but not have it forced on me.

I know that git has hooks, and so I'm imagining another solution may be to have a checkout hook produce a file which could act as a temporary **stop** sign to the watch task, or something similar.

Anyone experienced a similar issue using `watch` and how would you suggest solving it?

Comment: Won't `gulp-changed` or `gulp-newer` solve your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As specified in [@Mushr00m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458442/mushr00m)'s answer for [Gulp.js, watch task runs twice when saving files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548819/388006), there is a `debounceDelay` option you can pass to `gulp.watch()`.

> debounceDelay {integer} Delay for events called in succession for the
>   same file/event

In short, as a long as all of your changes happen at the same time, the `debounceDelay` will wait before triggering you watched tasks.  In my experiences, git is normally pretty quick, so you could set a `debounceDelay` of perhaps `500` or `1000` without much impact to your development workflow.

Example:

```
gulp.watch('/**/*.less', {debounceDelay: 2000}, ['less']);
```

I was able to verify this be digging through the documentation.  The actual functionality comes from [gaze](https://github.com/shama/gaze#properties).

Answer (score 4):

I am using [forever-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-monitor) to set up child processes for my watchers, and I realized I could watch `.git/HEAD` as a trigger for restarting my monitors.

My code looks like this:

```
return watch('./.git/HEAD', {name: 'Branch watcher'}, function(events, done) {
  monitors.forEach(function(monitor) {
    monitor.restart();
  });
});
```

You could easily replace my `monitor` management with any other code to execute on branch change:

```
return watch('./.git/HEAD', {name: 'Branch watcher'}, function(events, done) {
  // Do what needs to be done on branch change
});
```

If you have another watch running, it will be difficult to restart it without using something like `forever-monitor`, because killing gulp processes at the system level will kill your branch watcher. I set this up, though, and it works very smoothly.

Comment: Interesting, I will have to experiment with that.