# How to watch a file for changes effectively using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gulp, watch

I am looking for a stable way to watch for changes on a file using Node.js.
The easiest option `fs.watch` is [unstable according to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener). For me it works fine but it is always fired twice per a single change. The file is not [really changed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080132/nodejs-filesystem-watch-throwing-event-twice-or-more-often) (on my OSX) and using [EventMachine.watch_file](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.watch_file) the desired event is triggered exactly once per change.

However in [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) any watch-task also works fine: the event is triggered once per change.

So I have two questions: which library/function is used in gulp to watch file and how to use it instead of `fs.watch`? I am quite new to Node.js so surfing the sources of gulp didn't help me.

Comment: gulp uses https://github.com/shama/gaze currently.

Comment: (which doesn't use fs.watch)

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin_B mentioned, the answer is https://github.com/shama/gaze